# Windows 10 Mobile Ringtone and Notificaton Volume Adjustment

Tags: audio, notifications, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to change the volume for the "Ringer+Notifcation" and "Media+App" for the Windows 10 Mobile operating system using XAML(Universal App). The OS has the capability to change the volume, there gotta be a way to change the volume down programmatically. Please let me know if there is a way to access the system instead of waiting for the new SDK. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: ASFAK, it is impossible currently. UWP app is sandbox that you cannot change system settings as you want.  I don't think new SDK will provide this feature. Think about one app can change the volume as its want on  your phone, seriously.  So think about why you need this, app can change volume of the media or audio inside itself.

Comment: The android you can change the volume.  I really like to implement the volume control so i can schedule it to turn down the volume when I sleep. People just spam randomly like 2 or 3 clock in the morning, not fun at all.  I have to turn down the volume manually every night and turn up the volume during the day time for now.